# How to visit localhost from zombie during grunt-cucumber test?

Tags: node.js, cucumber, gruntjs, yeoman, zombie.js

## Task

We're using an angular app generated by yeoman and we want to use cucumberjs to test our app. I have replaced the default `grunt test` task's karma with [grunt-cucumber](https://github.com/s9tpepper/grunt-cucumber-js) (it is otherwise the same).

We have a support file that adds zombiejs to the world, world.js:

```
var Zombie = require('zombie');
var World = function(callback) {
  this.browser = new Zombie();

  callback();
};
exports.World = World;
```

Inside of a step definition there is:

```
this.World = require('../support/world.js');
...
this.browser.visit('http://localhost:9000/', callback);
```

## Problem

Which gives a 404 error:

`Error: Server returned status code 404 from http://localhost:9000/
    at /home/vagrant/Projects/ShadowWolf/client/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/window.js:411:23
    at /home/vagrant/Projects/ShadowWolf/client/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/eventloop.js:234:18
    at Object._onImmediate (/home/vagrant/Projects/ShadowWolf/client/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/eventloop.js:139:11)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)`

#### Troubleshooting

However, when I ran a local `grunt serer:test` and from a node prompt ran the same javascript as above, everything worked as expected (although I did get *"10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"* when I tried to print the text of the page -- which it did print).

## Question

So my question is, how should I be accessing a test version of the webpage from within my cucumberjs step_definition files?

Comment: did you run server:test before using grunt cucumber?